# Python gives lengthy output suggesting modules are being destroyed

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-import

So I was resolving some merge conflicts when I got this message:

```
commentaryAT/models.py: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The line this refers to looked like this:

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals)
```

Right behind that, I also got this error:

```
(hattie-nHCNXwaX) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/hattie$ 
commentaryAT/models.py
from: too many arguments
import-im6.q16: not authorized `uuid' @ 
error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
from: too many arguments
from: too many arguments
from: too many arguments
```

Note that in my frustration I was moving too fast and forgot to put 'git add' in front of the command 'commentaryAT/models.py'

So we went round and around with these two errors not being satisfied with anything I was doing to appease them, and I wondered if this was some weird Python2 error, so I decided to check the version, despite being inside a virtualenv. That now seems to have been a huge mistake:

```
(hattie-nHCNXwaX) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/hattie$ python -v
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installing zipimport hook
import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installed zipimport hook
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'posix' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _thread # previously loaded ('_thread')
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _weakref # previously loaded ('_weakref')
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/encodings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/encodings/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/encodings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc'
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/codecs.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/codecs.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/codecs.cpython-37.pyc'
import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'codecs' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cb8a278>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/encodings/__pycache__/aliases.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/encodings/aliases.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/encodings/__pycache__/aliases.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'encodings.aliases' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cb9ac50>
import 'encodings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cbfacc0>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/encodings/__pycache__/utf_8.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/encodings/utf_8.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/encodings/__pycache__/utf_8.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'encodings.utf_8' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cba9978>
import '_signal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/encodings/__pycache__/latin_1.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/encodings/latin_1.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/encodings/__pycache__/latin_1.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'encodings.latin_1' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cbaf470>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/io.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/io.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/io.cpython-37.pyc'
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/abc.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/abc.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/abc.cpython-37.pyc'
import '_abc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cbafa58>
import 'io' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cbaf6a0>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/site.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/site.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/site.cpython-37.pyc'
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/os.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/os.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/os.cpython-37.pyc'
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/stat.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/stat.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/stat.cpython-37.pyc'
import '_stat' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'stat' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cb4e470>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/posixpath.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/posixpath.cpython-37.pyc'
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/genericpath.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/genericpath.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/genericpath.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'genericpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cb50eb8>
import 'posixpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cb4eb38>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/_collections_abc.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/_collections_abc.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/_collections_abc.cpython-37.pyc'
import '_collections_abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cb5d550>
import 'os' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cb420b8>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/_bootlocale.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/_bootlocale.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/_bootlocale.cpython-37.pyc'
import '_locale' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_bootlocale' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cb42438>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/types.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/types.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/types.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'types' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cafd390>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/importlib/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/importlib/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc'
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/warnings.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/warnings.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/warnings.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'warnings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735caf8080>
import 'importlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cafd438>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/importlib/__pycache__/util.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/importlib/util.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/importlib/__pycache__/util.cpython-37.pyc'
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/importlib/__pycache__/abc.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/importlib/abc.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/importlib/__pycache__/abc.cpython-37.pyc'
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/importlib/__pycache__/machinery.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/importlib/machinery.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/importlib/__pycache__/machinery.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'importlib.machinery' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cb05be0>
import 'importlib.abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cb05390>
# /usr/local/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/contextlib.cpython-37.pyc matches /usr/local/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py
# code object from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/contextlib.cpython-37.pyc'
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/collections/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/collections/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc'
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/operator.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/operator.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/operator.cpython-37.pyc'
import '_operator' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'operator' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735b9d0e10>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/keyword.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/keyword.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/keyword.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'keyword' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735b9d9f98>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/heapq.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/heapq.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/heapq.cpython-37.pyc'
# extension module '_heapq' loaded from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
# extension module '_heapq' executed from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
import '_heapq' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7f735b9e2e48>
import 'heapq' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735b9e2908>
import 'itertools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/reprlib.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/reprlib.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/reprlib.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'reprlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735b9e2f28>
import '_collections' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'collections' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cb19fd0>
# /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/functools.cpython-37.pyc matches /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/functools.py
# code object from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/functools.cpython-37.pyc'
import '_functools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'functools' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735b9b7400>
import 'contextlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cb14898>
import 'importlib.util' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735caf8668>
# possible namespace for /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zope
# possible namespace for /home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zope
# destroy zope
import 'site' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f735cbb4630>
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 19 2018, 17:20:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
# extension module 'readline' loaded from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
# extension module 'readline' executed from '/home/malikarumi/.local/share/virtualenvs/hattie-nHCNXwaX/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
import 'readline' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7f735caec1d0>
>>> exit()
# clear builtins._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.__interactivehook__
# clear sys.flags
# clear sys.float_info
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup[2] removing sys
# cleanup[2] removing builtins
# cleanup[2] removing _frozen_importlib
# cleanup[2] removing _imp
# cleanup[2] removing _thread
# cleanup[2] removing _warnings
# cleanup[2] removing _weakref
# cleanup[2] removing zipimport
# cleanup[2] removing _frozen_importlib_external
# cleanup[2] removing _io
# cleanup[2] removing marshal
# cleanup[2] removing posix
# cleanup[2] removing encodings
# destroy encodings
# cleanup[2] removing codecs
# cleanup[2] removing _codecs
# cleanup[2] removing encodings.aliases
# cleanup[2] removing encodings.utf_8
# cleanup[2] removing _signal
# cleanup[2] removing __main__
# destroy __main__
# cleanup[2] removing encodings.latin_1
# cleanup[2] removing io
# destroy io
# cleanup[2] removing abc
# cleanup[2] removing _abc
# cleanup[2] removing site
# destroy site
# cleanup[2] removing os
# cleanup[2] removing stat
# cleanup[2] removing _stat
# cleanup[2] removing posixpath
# cleanup[2] removing genericpath
# cleanup[2] removing os.path
# cleanup[2] removing _collections_abc
# cleanup[2] removing _bootlocale
# destroy _bootlocale
# cleanup[2] removing _locale
# cleanup[2] removing types
# cleanup[2] removing importlib
# destroy importlib
# cleanup[2] removing importlib._bootstrap
# cleanup[2] removing importlib._bootstrap_external
# cleanup[2] removing warnings
# cleanup[2] removing importlib.util
# cleanup[2] removing importlib.abc
# cleanup[2] removing importlib.machinery
# cleanup[2] removing contextlib
# destroy contextlib
# cleanup[2] removing collections
# destroy collections
# cleanup[2] removing operator
# destroy operator
# cleanup[2] removing _operator
# cleanup[2] removing keyword
# destroy keyword
# cleanup[2] removing heapq
# cleanup[2] removing _heapq
# cleanup[2] removing itertools
# cleanup[2] removing reprlib
# destroy reprlib
# cleanup[2] removing _collections
# cleanup[2] removing functools
# cleanup[2] removing _functools
# cleanup[2] removing zope
# destroy zope
# cleanup[2] removing readline
# destroy zipimport
# destroy _signal
# destroy posixpath
# destroy _stat
# destroy genericpath
# destroy os
# destroy stat
# destroy _locale
# destroy importlib.util
# destroy importlib.abc
# destroy functools
# destroy types
# destroy importlib.machinery
# destroy warnings
# destroy abc
# destroy _collections_abc
# destroy heapq
# destroy _operator
# destroy _heapq
# destroy itertools
# destroy _collections
# destroy _abc
# destroy _functools
# destroy readline
# cleanup[3] wiping _frozen_importlib
# destroy _frozen_importlib_external
# cleanup[3] wiping _imp
# cleanup[3] wiping _thread
# cleanup[3] wiping _warnings
# cleanup[3] wiping _weakref
# cleanup[3] wiping _io
# cleanup[3] wiping marshal
# cleanup[3] wiping posix
# cleanup[3] wiping codecs
# cleanup[3] wiping _codecs
# cleanup[3] wiping encodings.aliases
# cleanup[3] wiping encodings.utf_8
# cleanup[3] wiping encodings.latin_1
# cleanup[3] wiping importlib._bootstrap
# cleanup[3] wiping sys
# cleanup[3] wiping builtins
(hattie-nHCNXwaX) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/hattie$
```

I have no idea what most of that means, but I do find words like "wiping" and "destroy" disconcerting in this context. I googled around, and most of my hits were from bugs.python.org.

In [this one](https://bugs.python.org/issue33719) no less than Ned Batchelder posted a very long output similar to what I pasted here. He also had just used the 'python -v' command. But they report that issue as fixed and closed. I got a similar output but from a different cause. He was using Pydoc at the time.

How serious is this? Have I actually lost all these files? What can be done about it?

Comment: Your script file apparently doesn't start with a shebang line.  Typing its pathname in your shell is therefore running it as a shell script, rather than a Python program - none of those errors could possibly be generated by Python.  (All of that text you got from `python -v` is perfectly normal.  `python -V` is how you'd simply check the version number.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `python -v` is for verbose output (read: debug output). The output that you got is pretty normal.

Type `python -V` (capital V) if you just want to check the version ;-)

This is the relevant part from the help (`python -?`):

```
-v     : verbose (trace import statements); also PYTHONVERBOSE=x
         can be supplied multiple times to increase verbosity
-V     : print the Python version number and exit (also --version)
         when given twice, print more information about the build
```

*NB: The terms "removing", "destroy" and "wiping" in the log all refer to Python internal objects (modules) that were loaded by the Python interpreter. They are not removed from your system, but just unloaded from the interpreter while shutting down. So the command `python -v ...` does exactly the same as `python ...`, except that it also prints a lot of debug information that most users normally won't care about.*

Comment: Yea, gotta watch those capitals. Python is case sensitive, so I'm told. Thx.

Comment: I can't believe this only has 2 upvotes!! I thought I would be fighting it all day long. Thanks @wovano